# Run-time for .NET core applications on linux

Tags: .net-core

I am a bit confused with .NET core applications running on linux. For .NET core applications to run on linux, do we have to install .NET core on linux ? .NET core applications are cross-platform because of the run-time, does this run-time has to been installed on the linux machine first or will it be part of the .NET core application. How does run-time differentiate between different operating systems ?

Comment: `does this run-time has to been installed` - [yes](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2).

Comment: @GSerg No, it doesn't. That's what self-contained apps are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the application was published. You can do Framework Dependent Deployments, where the framework must be installed on the server. Or you can do Self Contained Deployments, where the necessary bits are bundled along with the app. More information is available in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/).

Comment: ok, thanks @mason . I have another question, we can install .NET core on linux machine but we cannot install .NET framework on linux machine, why ?

Comment: @WaleedNaveed Because .NET Framework was written specifically for Windows, nearly 20 years ago. That's why some people created the Mono project.